# how make file upload field through custom field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to make file upload field in Advance custom field plugin and I find many reference code on ACF 'https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/',
stack overflow, stack exchange WordPress development and I also refer WP begginner, kinsta.com but they gave solution for plugin like how to use WP Form plugin. I want it to make it without plugin through custom field. If anyone knows plz give your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Doesn't the ACF built-in [File field type](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/) (that you posted the link to) do exactly what you want?

Comment: If not, you'll need to [make a field type](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/) with the upload input control and then probably [wp_handle_upload()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_upload/) on submission, then do whatever you want to with the file data.

Comment: Do you mean to add it through a frontend form that you have custom built?

Comment: Yes, like I create input field for file in custom field and want to upload file

Comment: Yea this quite a process though. Because you will need to upload the file manually through the form submission or through Ajax. The file needs to be stored in wp-content/uploads and then you can save the URL in the custom field if you like. I have a full example that matches your description.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the following in your form, php files and your JS.

Pay close attention to the approach, because it won't suit you. I am storing the file URL in the custom field. Possibly you prefer another way to store your file.

First you need to add two HTML input fields. Add a input type file to your form as well as a hidden field

```
<input class="input_file" type="file" id="file" name="input_file" />
<input type="hidden" class="hidden-file-field" name="hidden_file_field" />
```

JS
Here we check for file field changes and do a ajax request. Pay attention to the "global" variable name because it's actually set in PHP's localize_script below.

Main strategy here is actually to save the file in a hidden field that is later going to be submitted in the form.

```
    $imgFile.on('change', function(e) {
    
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = new FormData();

        var files = $('input[name="input_file"]').prop('files')[0];
        data.append('input_file', files);

        data.append('nonce', global.nonce);
        data.append('action', 'media_upload')
        var data_type = 'image';

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: global.ajax,
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

                if ( myXhr.upload ) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', function(e) {

                    }, false );
                }

                return myXhr;
            },
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function() {
                // handle before send
            },
            success: function(resp) {
                // handle success
                // Save the result the url or attachment ID in a hidden input field and when the overall form is submitted, save it in the custom field.

                $('.hidden-file-field').val(resp.url)



            }
        });

    })
```

PHP:
We first need to include a nonce for submitting the media field
Then we need to have the function that actually uploads the file data and return a url and some other data. This is done with add_action for ajax submissions.

```
   // Localize script is needed to have the nonce included
   wp_localize_script(

        'jsfilename',
        'global',
        array(
            'ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'nonce'      => wp_create_nonce('media-form')
        )
    );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_media_upload', 'media_upload' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_media_upload', 'media_upload');


function media_upload(){

    if ( check_ajax_referer( 'media-form', 'nonce', false ) == false ) {
        wp_send_json_error(array('error' => 'nonce failed'));
    }

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');


    if (isset($_FILES['input_file'] ) && !empty($_FILES['input_file']['name']) )
    {
        $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "pdf");


        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["input_file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        if ( in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
            if ( ($_FILES["input_file"]["error"] > 0) && ($_FILES['input_file']['size'] <= 3145728 ))
            {
                $response = array(
                    "status" => 'error',
                    "message" => 'ERROR Return Code: '. $_FILES["input_file"]["error"],
                );
            }
            else
            {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['input_file'];
                $upload_name = $_FILES['input_file']['name'];
                $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
                $filepath = $uploads['path']."/$upload_name";

                if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) )
                {
                    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
                }
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
                $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
                $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
                if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] )  ) {

                    $file = $movefile['file'];
                    $url = $movefile['url'];
                    $type = $movefile['type'];

                    $attachment = array(
                        'post_mime_type' => $type ,
                        'post_title' => $upload_name,
                        'post_content' => 'File '.$upload_name,
                        'post_status' => 'inherit'
                    );

                    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, 0);
                    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

                }

                $response = array(
                    "status" => 'success',
                    "url" => $url,
                    "attachment_id" => $attach_id
                );

            }
        }
        else
        {
            $response = array(
                "status" => 'error',
                "message" => 'something went wrong, most likely file is to large for upload. check upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and memory_limit in you php.ini',
            );
        }
    }

        wp_send_json_success($response);


}
```

In the end, when you submit your form, with AJAX or normal POST, you should use below. Most likely you are going to sanitize the $POST first. I leave that up to you:

```
update_field('name_of_file_field', $POST['hidden_file_field'] $post_id);
```